# readline - deleting word under cursor

Tags: linux, bash, readline

E.g. `Alt-d` deletes word until next word boundary. There's also a shortcut to delete until previous word boundary IIRC, but I'd like to delete word UNDER cursor (i.e. to current word left boundary and next word boundary).

Is this even available in readline?

Comment: `Alt-Backspace` deletes to *previous* word boundary. Not sure if there's a way to map a keystroke to `Alt-d Alt-Backspace`

Answer (score 2):

OK found it: you can create key bindings to "macros": http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/readline.3readline.html

First, choose a key combination you want to use for this "kill whole word" operation -- peruse `bind -sp | sort | less` to see what's in use.

Suppose <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> is OK, then

```
echo '"\C-x\C-w": "\ed\e\C-h"' >> ~/.inputrc
```

Start a new shell, and you should be good to go.

Although <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> is just as easy/awkward as <kbd>Alt-d</kbd><kbd>Alt-Backspace</kbd>